# Proximo ID para chave primaria composta

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de exemplo para a tabela pessoas:

```
CREATE TABLE `pessoas` (
`i_entidade` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`i_pessoas` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`nome` char(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`nome_fantasia` char(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`tipo_pessoa` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`ativo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`date_create` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `pessoas`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`i_entidade`,`i_pessoas`);
COMMIT;
```

Como percebe-se a aplicação será multi-entidade. Cada entidade que terá acesso ao cadastro de pessoas, somente poderá manipular os dados referente a sua entidade. Então segue um exemplo desta tabela preenchida:

```
(pessoas)
| i_entidades | i_pessoas |  nome  |
|      1      |     1     |  João  |
|      1      |     2     |  José  |
|      2      |     1     |  João  |
|      2      |     2     |  Maria |
|      2      |     3     |  José  |
|      3      |     1     |  José  |
|      3      |     2     |  João  |
```

Preciso primeiro antes de fazer o `INSERT` buscar a próxima chave para poder fazer a inserção já que chave primaria composta não aceita `AUTO INCREMENT`, então logo na cabeça vem o uso da seguinte `QUERY` para conseguir o valor para a entidade número 1 por exemplo:

```
SELECT MAX(i_pessoas)+1 AS i_pessoas FROM pessoas WHERE i_entidades = 1;
```

Minha dúvida é se realmente está e a melhor opção para este problema?
Está `QUERY` tem uma particularidade também que só retorna `NULL` caso não tiver nenhuma linha inserida para a tal entidade.

A aplicação está sendo desenvolvida na linguagem `PHP` e utilizando um banco `MYSQL`.

Comment: Já que vai retornar NULL, você poderia deixar esse "+1" pra depois que receber o resultado no PHP. Me parece mais seguro... O que acha?

Comment: @MatteusBarbosa então queria saber se está e a unica opção e a forma correta para esta situação.

Comment: Então.. pra mim não é a única, mas você chegou na melhor maneira. Eu faria como você fez, com essa pequena alteração, porque adição de nulo +1 vai retornar nulo.

Comment: E vai dar certo. Como falou resolve o problema do null. Eu usava essa técnica em projetos mais antigos. Vou retomar o projeto semana que vem.